# SignalR not calling client methods from the server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, signalr

I'm adding all my client methods before I call .start().

What I'm doing is loading wiring up all the client methods and I've got a setTimeout for 5 seconds to actually call .start(), so I know all my client script is wired up.

For some reason the scripted gets wired up but will not be called be the server.

Now, I'm able to call the server methods with no problems, I just need the server to relay that message back to the clients, via the client script.

Is it OK to put client script inside named function objects?

I've removed a lot of the code so it is readable.

**This works, because I'm calling the server.**

```
$.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.server.sendMsg
```

-

**This does not work because I'm waiting on the server to send the client it's message**

```
 $.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.client.receiveMsg
```

=

**On the server side when I debug I am receiving the sentMsg from the client to the server and the receiveMsg is being called from the server, but it never makes it to the client.**

```
    function ChatBox(collaboratorMenuItem) {

    var 
        sendMsg = function (ev) {
            // If the user has pressed enter

            if (ev.keyCode === 13) {

                if (this.value.trim() === '') { return false; };

                var avatar = attendees.querySelector('.' + meAttendee.profile.UserID);
                if (avatar) {

                    chats.appendChild(
                           docCreateAttrs('div', { 'class': 'collabChat', innerHTML: this.value }).addChild(avatar.cloneNode(true))
                           );
                } else {
                    chats.appendChild(
                          docCreateAttrs('div', { 'class': 'collabChat', innerHTML: this.value })
                          );
                };

                $.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.server.sendMsg({ msg: this.value });

                this.value = '';
                return false;
            } else { return true; };
        },



    debugger
    //Callbacks that are called from the server. Not intended for local function calls
    $.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.client.receiveMsg = function (cmsg) {

        var avatar = attendees.querySelector('.' + cmsg.uid);
        if (avatar) {

            chats.appendChild(
                   docCreateAttrs('div', { 'class': 'collabChat', innerHTML: cmsg.msg }).addChild(avatar.cloneNode(true))
                   );
        } else {
            chats.appendChild(
                  docCreateAttrs('div', { 'class': 'collabChat', innerHTML: cmsg.msg })
                  );
        };
    };
    $.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.client.addCurrAttendee = function (attendee) {

        debugger
        addAttendee(attendee);
    };
    $.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.client.joined = function (attendee) {
        debugger
        addAttendee(attendee);

        //let the new attendee know about you
        if (attendee.cnnid !== meAttendee.cnnid) {
            meAttendee.newbieid = attendee.cnnid;
            //
            this.server.addMeNewbie(meAttendee);
        };
    };
    $.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.client.rejoined = function (attendee) {
        debugger
        //console.log('Re joined : ' + attendee.cnnid);
        addAttendee(attendee);

        //let the new attendee know about you
        if (attendee.cnnid !== meAttendee.cnnid) {

            meAttendee.newbieid = attendee.cnnid;
            this.server.addMeNewbie(meAttendee);
        };
    };
    $.connection.hub.proxies.collaboratorhub.client.gone = function (attendee) {
        // console.log('gone : ' + attendee.cnnid);
        removeAttendee(attendee);
    };

    collaboratorMenuItem.onclick = function (e) {
        //debugger
        if (!chatBox.parentNode) {
            var xy = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

            document.body.appendChild(chatBox.setGX(null, xy.left).setGY(null, xy.height));
            $(chatBox).draggable({ handle: chatHead, cursor: "move" }).css('position', 'absolute').resizable();
        } else {
            removeChat();
        };
    };

    return {
        chatBox: chatBox,
        attendLk: attendLk,
        addAttendee: addAttendee,
        removeAttendee: removeAttendee,
        removeChat: removeChat
    };
};
```

--This is how I create a name function called `collaborateManager` that when instantiated has a property call `this.chatBox` and this is where all the client script is loaded up, with-in the `ChatBox`.

The collaboratorMenuItem is just a div that the ChatBox is placed next to.

```
  function collaborateManager(collaboratorMenuItem) {



                this.chatBox = new ChatBox(collaboratorMenuItem);


    }


    return {
        hideCollaborator: hideCollaborator,
        showCollaborator: showCollaborator,
        getCollaborator: getCollaborator,
        removeCollaboratorCollaborators: removeCollaborator
    };
```

---

And in another Global JS File I start the connect in five seconds.

```
document.bindReady(function () {

setTimeout(function () {

    //Global SignalR Connections State

    var cnnStateChanged = function (change) {

        if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.reconnecting) {
            console.log('Re-connecting');
        }
        else if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {

            console.log('The server is online');
        }
        else if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {

            console.log('The server is offline');
        };
    },
     cnnReconnected = function (change) {

         if (change && change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.reconnected) {

         };
         console.log('The server is re-connected');
     };
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Global start SignalR connectio

    $.connection.hub.stateChanged(cnnStateChanged);
    $.connection.hub.reconnected(cnnReconnected);

    if ($.connection.hub && $.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            //debugger
            // onConnected();
        });
    } else {
        //debugger
        // onConnected();
    };

},5000);
```

});

---

The connection is starting correctly each time, that is not the issue, I can send server messages as well, I need to be able to receive those messages.

**Here is my server side sendMsg that gets called, but no clients ever receive the receiveMsg()**

```
  public Task sendMsg(Cmsg cmsg)
    {
        string pid = this.Context.QueryString["pid"],
               uid = this.Context.QueryString["uid"];
        //
        cmsg.cnnid = Context.ConnectionId;
        cmsg.uid = uid;
        //614

        return Clients.OthersInGroup(pid).receiveMsg(cmsg);
    }
```

Any suggestions? Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I need help on this right away, if anyone can assist that would be great. Throw me a bone.

Comment: I was able to get it to work but I've got to place the all the startup stuff as in, .start() directly under the client events that are being wired up, which is not ideal. I had my hopes set on  two different types of chats on one page, thought process was to wire up all the client stuff then when I know it's all loaded up call .start(), and I should be good to go. Unless someone can show me I'm really not doing this correctly I smell a few iFrames coming on. And, oh, how i love those little pesky iFrames.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your server side code to:

```
public Task sendMsg(Cmsg cmsg)
{
   string pid = this.Context.QueryString["pid"],
   uid = this.Context.QueryString["uid"];
   //
   cmsg.cnnid = Context.ConnectionId;
   cmsg.uid = uid;
   //614
   return Clients.Caller.OthersInGroup(pid).receiveMsg(cmsg);
}
```

Adding the **Caller** in:  return Clients.Caller.OthersInGroup(pid).receiveMsg(cmsg);